# How to avoid 'Index out of Bound' exceptions with Protractor ElementArrayFinder

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium, promise, protractor

I am pretty new to Protractor and I am using it with conjunction with chai and chai-as-promised. Currently I am trying to figure out how to best handle a situation, when my `ElementArrayFinder` doesn't contain the elements that I need.

For an `ElementFinder` (no Array) it seems pretty simple:

```
element(by.css('.neverthere')).isPresent().then(function(value){
    console.log('IsPresent() for .neverthere is: ', value, '\n');
});
```

The code above doesn't throw an exception and `isPresent()` returns `false`, once the promise is evaluated.

Once I start using `ElementArrayFinders`, it gets more complicated:

```
var el = element.all(by.repeater(
                'property in propertyPanel.properties'))
        .first()
        .all(by.css('.neverthere'))
        .first();

el.isPresent().then(function(value){
    console.log('IsPresent() for ', name, ' is: ', value, '\n');
});
```

The code above throws an `Error: Index out of bound.` exception for the evaluation of `isPresent()`, when the array, on which `first()` is evaluated, is empty.

Is there a way to access elements from an `ElementArrayFinder`, so that - if the element isn't present - an `ElementFinder` is returned that answers 'false' to `isPresent()`, instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am seeing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just assert that the [count](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) of elements found is 0:

```
var elements = element.all(by.repeater('property in propertyPanel.properties')).all(by.css('.neverthere'));
expect(elements.count()).toBe(0);
```

Using `first()` in conjunction with `browser.isElementPresent()`:

```
var elements = element.all(by.repeater('property in propertyPanel.properties')).all(by.css('.neverthere'));
expect(browser.isElementPresent(elements.first()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: I know that I can assert on the count, however my goal is to have a generic element finder and have it separate from the expect() clause. That means I'd like to be able to have the element finder method perform the full evaluation and - if no element is found - return a result that answers "false" to isPresent().

Comment: @Bernhard I understand and you have an interesting problem to solve. In theory, [`first()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) should work since it returns an `ElementFinder` out of an `ElementArrayFinder`. I've updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit late, but anyway will put it there.
Yesterday I faced exactly the same issue, and after brief investigation of protractor's sources found one interesting method:

```
ElementArrayFinder.prototype.toElementFinder_ = function() {
  return new ElementFinder(this.ptor_, this);
};
```

And realized that all ElementFinder instances being costracted from ElementArrayFinder instances and just tooks first element from it, throws "No element found using locator" in case if ElementArrayFinder doesn't contain any elements and puts a warning "more than one element found for locator" in case there are more than one element in ElementArrayFinder.

So, as a workaround for "Error: Index out of bound." in isPresent() on element received from ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first we can use internal method ElementArrayFinder.prototype.toElementFinder_ like this:

```
var el = element.all(by.repeater(
            'property in propertyPanel.properties'))
    .first()
    .all(by.css('.neverthere'))
    .toElementFinder_();

el.isPresent().then(function(value){
    console.log('IsPresent() for ', name, ' is: ', value, '\n');
});
```

Example above will work as expected: exactly as

```
element(by.css('.neverthere')).isPresent().then(function(value){})
```

does.

Answer (score 0):

syntext error in your code, you have add the index for second element finder

```
 var el = element.all(by.repeater(
                    'property in propertyPanel.properties')).get(0)
            .all(by.css('.neverthere'))
            .first();
```

Comment: Hi Azzi, thanks for finding this. My original statement was much more complicated and I trimmed it down for clarity, unfortunately a bit too much. In any case, do you have any idea to solve my original problem?